# Use support library in android projects and library (Android Studio)

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-support-library, android-studio

I'm using the new Android Studio, I'm looking for a way to use the support library from multiple projects. Basically I have a project that uses the `ActionBarSherlock` this projects requires the support library. So I added a reference as like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16580586/995926).

Now I have the problem that my main project also uses the support library so I have it includes twice in some way. If I remove the library from one of both projects I'll get errors that some support library related classes are unknown which is clear for me, but if I have a reference in both projects I'll face this error:

```
Android Dex: [ProjectName] UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
Android Dex: [ProjectName] java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: already added: Landroid/support/v4/app/ShareCompat$ShareCompatImplJB;
Android Dex: [ProjectName] at com.android.dx.dex.file.ClassDefsSection.add(ClassDefsSection.java:123)
Android Dex: [ProjectName] at com.android.dx.dex.file.DexFile.add(DexFile.java:163)
Android Dex: [ProjectName] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processClass(Main.java:490)
Android Dex: [ProjectName] at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.processFileBytes(Main.java:459)
...
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: i guess you have to remove the jar from tour project and try.

Comment: @Raghunandan did you note this: *"[...] If I remove the libary from one of both projects I'll get errors that some support library related classes are unknown[...]"*

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I fixed this by going into `File > Project Structure...` and selecting `Modules` then click on the module's `Dependencies` tab. Then next to the library I changed the scope from `Compile` to `Provided`.

This means the module can still use it, but it doesn't reach compile, since I assume you are already using that JAR in your main project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Provided is no longer an option in Android Studio 0.4.0. Is there any way to specify this behavior in the Gradle file?

Comment: @Greg change compile 'source' to provide 'source'

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue happen to me. Select `actionbarsherlock` in the project tab/bar/whatever (on the left, so you can see the project tree). hit `F4` to open the module settings.
Make sure that you are **not using the same dependencies twice** in actionbarsherlock and your project.
Also make sure that you're using the version of the support library that's in the **android-studio sdk** (`android-studio/sdk/extras/android`).

Finally, if you're like me, make sure you didn't accidentally make actionbarsherlock dependent on itself, thus loading the library twice THAT way! >.<

Take a look at these images showing my module preferences:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/eiHvQ.jpg 
[image: Actionbar Sherlock]
[image]

Also, don't forget to make sure `libs` isn't hiding any of the same ones!

Answer (score 0):

Did this use to be an Eclipse project? If so try going into Eclipse, clean the project, exit, rebuild in IntelliJ. I believe this is a state-issue, not a configuration issue.

Comment: I needed one hour to fix a wired eclipse error. However this does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of importing android support library as jar, I changed the libraries (in my case facebook sdk) dependencies in build.gradle to:

```
dependencies {
    compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:13.0.0'
 }
```