# How to import Android Support Library to project?

Tags: android, sdk, android-studio

How do I import the Android Support Library into my Android Studio project?

I need it to use fragments, apparently. 
I have downloaded the Android Support Library and the Android Support Repository from SDK Manager, and I've read that I'm suppose to go to File -> Project Structure -> Dependencies and click on the + button and add the file.

But where do i find it? I have looked in the Android Studios folder but I can't find it anywhere?

Thanks!

Comment: Here you have what you are looking for: [Add support library to Android Studio project][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580586/add-support-library-to-android-studio-project

Comment: No help, i've already done that but I dont find the file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you download it from `Android Studio` (Tools -> Android -> SDK manager)
You can obtain path to SDK from menu. Just launch `SDK manager`
And get the `SDK Path` (Line over the packages)

So now you can find support library by following way:
`"SDK Path"\extras\android\support`

Answer (score 0):

You mean on your hard drive? This should be the path:

`MY_SDK_LOCATION/sdk/extras/android/support`