# How to use support libraries in android studio?

Tags: java, android

I was wondering how to use the android support libraries(android.support.v4 or v7) in android studios? It says they are unrecognized when i try to import them.

Comment: http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to File -> Project Structure -> app -> Dependencies

Click the plus icon on the right hand side, select Library Dependency and add the required support libraries from there.

[image]

Comment: i added both of those to my current project, yet it still gives me an error. Why?

Comment: I don't know why you might be seeing this error, check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580586/add-support-library-to-android-studio-project)

Comment: nvm. I made a new project, and it seemed to work in the new one. I guess ill just delete the other one. Thank you!