# i have some views within a scrollview.i want to change the title of the actionbar while scrolling up

Tags: android, android-actionbar

i have some views within a scrollview in a xml file.i want to change the title of the action bar while scrolling up.anyaone please help me how to do that..

this is my xml file

```
<ScrollView 
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >
    <LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="name"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="email"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="address"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

Comment: use onscrollchnage and up date title whenever scroll is changed

Answer (score 1):

You want to observe the scrollview's scrolling? For whatever reason you *can't* do this via the Android SDK for scrollviews (you can for listviews however). As a result there are whole libraries!

https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Or you can easily implement something similar fairly simpply such as
https://stackoverflow.com/a/3952629/3865761 if it meets your needs. Standing on the shoulders of stack overflow giant's as it were.

Once you can detect the scrolling, simply have methods such as onScrollUp() that increases the font size for your textviews, and resetTextViewState() which sets it back to its default called from the onScrollingChanged() callback you implement.

Comment: but i don't have a list view.i am designing this xml file only for a my profile page.and i want on scrolling up ,name of the person should appear in action bar.so can i use this lib  https://github.com/ksoichiro/Android-ObservableScrollView

Comment: but i don't have a list view.i am designing this xml file only for a my profile page.and i want on scrolling up ,name of the person should appear in action bar

Comment: You are free to use the lib, just check the license. Although the lib might be overkill, if you check the stack overflow link I posted, it contains some sample code for setting up a simple callback that will tell you when and how the scroll view is being scrolled. At which point, depending on the arguments passed, you can hide/show the person in the actionbar.

Comment: how can i design a activity in androd like truecaller application's (version 5.22) my profile page .

Comment: You have to implement the effects you want by listening to the callback that triggers when scrolling happen. Ie, if you wanted to change the size of the title text in the action bar, you would first set up the 'onScrolled' callback from your scrollview to the Activity, then compute the size of the text based on the scroll amount or position, then change the size of the textview. Or you can find a library to do this for you, something like https://android-arsenal.com/details/1/1577

Comment: thanks for ur response.bt one thing.i am using eclipse .so can i use this lib or i have to use android studio.

Comment: You can import it into Eclipse, mark it as a library project then import it into your app. But you should update to Android Studio.

Comment: thanks.ok How do I add a library (android-support-v7-appcompat) to android studio.actually i ceated a sample application using android studio.
i am new to android studio.en eclipse we have a option in file->proporties there we can add a lib to a project.bt in android studio hw can we add a lib  to a project.and i want to add  (android-support-v7-appcompat) .hw can i do that.plz tell me step by step

Comment: Simple google search will give you a lot of step by step instructions, you can see one such stack overflow post here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16580586/add-support-library-to-android-studio-project